# Problems with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

Actually I've installed nouveau drivers for my 1050 Ti but sometimes I see some lag on animations so I want to change the drivers. I tried the official Nvidia drivers, but at the reboot he's shown to me a violet screen and I can't do anything. So I tried an external repo and installed the 387 version of drivers, but I had the same problem. What I have to do?

Comment: Which external repo?

Comment: ppa:graphics-drivers

Comment: That's peculiar. I have a 1050 TI myself and don't see any animation lag. It may be a compatibility issue with your CPU/integration with other hardware, not just the graphics drivers. Have you tried updating your CPU model drivers and running a generic `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried it

Answer (score 0):

I have that same card and use that same ppa, but am running the 384 drivers, and they work well. (They just got an update yesterday outside of the ppa, from the main Ubuntu repos).

Try these steps

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375 nvidia-settings
```

(note 375 is a transitional package for 384, so nvidia-384 is also installed)

I suppose you could just install nvidia-384, but I haven't actually tried that myself.

Comment: I've tried with nvidia-375 but I had the same problem, I'll try with the -384

Comment: Nothing, i'm still having this type of problem